# Check duplicates of certain field for documents array with inner array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 objects,

```
  {   
     _id: ObjectId("5cd9010310b80b3e38cd3f88") 
     subGroup: [
       bookList: [ 
         {
            title: "A good book",
            id: "abc123"
         }
       ]    
      ] 
  }

{    
     _id: ObjectId("5cd9010710b80b3e38cd3f89") 
     subGroup: [
       bookList: [ 
         {
            title: "A good book",
            id: "abc123"
         }
       ]
```

These are 2 different objects. I would like to detect the occurence of these 2 objects where the title is duplicated (eg the same).

I tried this query

```
 db.scope.aggregate({"$unwind": "$subGroup.bookList"}, {"$group" : { "_id": "$title", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } }, {"$match": {"id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } })
```

which i looked at other threads on stackoverflow. However, it does not return me anything. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues here:

- `$unwind` should be run on `subGroup` and on `subGroup.bookList` separately
- when specifying `_id` for `$group` stage you should use full path (`subGroup.bookList.title`)
- in your `$match` stage you want to check if `_id` (not `id`) is `$ne` `null`

Try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$subGroup"}, 
    {"$unwind": "$subGroup.bookList"},
    {"$group" : { "_id": "$subGroup.bookList.title", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
    {"$match": { "_id" :{ "$ne" : null } , "count" : { "$gt": 1} } } 
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2hqVPEE3PY6)